# jQuery navgoco make working in li containing more links

Tags: jquery, html, css

please, do you have any tips, who to make working navgoco, is my menu looks like this:

```
<li>
    <a href="#" title="Open new level">+</a>
    <a href="link_somewhere">Some link title</a> <!-- link to edit -->
    <a href="link_somewhere">Some link title</a> <!-- link to delete --> 
    <ul>
       <!-- some other links with same style as parent has... -->
    </ul>
</li>
```

Problem is in more link in li... but I need to have them to control categories ("menu" is multilevel cateogries tree).

How to make it working?

Comment: What are you getting that you think is wrong?  You haven't actually described any problems or explained what is not working.  Please describe/post you current output and your expected output.

Comment: Oh, sorry. Ok, problem is, that plugin hide sub **ul** but if I click at **li**, containing **ul**, it won't display it. I think, problem is, that in **li** are more than just one **a** element...